# TikZ: offsetting a fill pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

TikZ provides fill patterns (section 15.5.1 in the docs).

> Instead of filling a path with a single solid color, it is also possible to fill it with a tiling pattern. Imagine a
> small tile that contains a simple picture like a star. Then these tiles are (conceptually) repeated infinitely
> in all directions, but clipped against the path.

Is there an option to offset the pattern? So that the tiles at the edge of the pattern are (conceptually) cut off at a specific place?

I tried combining `pattern` with `clip`, but it didn't change anything.

```
\clip (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
\fill [pattern color=black, pattern=fivepointed stars] (-0.8, -0.7) rectangle (1, 1);
```

---

Both

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[pattern color=black, pattern=fivepointed stars] (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
\fill[pattern color=black, pattern=fivepointed stars] (-0.2, -0.3) rectangle (1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produce

[image]

I am looking for a way to get something like this

[image]

where the pattern is just offset compared to the first drawing.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you want exactly. Could you provide a small complete document with a `tikzpicture` in it to illustrate the situation, in two versions side by side, one without clip and one with clip, and add a screenshot to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `patterns.meta` library is possible to define `shifting` for certain patterns.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,patterns.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=Stars, pattern color=red] (0,0) rectangle +(1, 1);

\draw[pattern={Stars[xshift=2pt,yshift=3pt]}, pattern color=blue] (0,0) rectangle +(1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `pgfmanual.pdf`, which is the documentation for Tikz and PGF, v. 3.1.4b, p. 1152, we read:

> Second, the phase of patterns is not well-defined, that is, it is not
> clear where the origin of the “first” tile is. To be more precise,
> PostScript and pdf on the one hand and svg on the other hand define
> the origin differently. PostScript and pdf define a fixed origin that
> is independent of where the path lies. This has the highly desirable
> effect that if you use the same pattern to fill multiple paths, the
> outcome is the same as if you had filled a single path consisting of
> the union of all these paths. By comparison, svg uses the upper-left
> (?) corner of the path to be filled as the origin. However, the svg
> specification is a bit vague on this question.

So, the answer to your question is: *no*.